# Windows 7 auto suggest is not working

Tags: windows-7

Like in earlier versions of windows (e.g windows XP), I can't see any previously visited list in the drop down menu of windows explorer of windows 7. Instead it is showing empty drop down list in windows explorer.
Do you have any idea how to resolve this?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Source [Enable, disable Autocomplete & Inline AutoComplete in Windows Explorer & Internet Explorer](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/enable-disable-autocomplete-inline-autocomplete-windows-explorer-internet-explorer)

> You may not have noticed it, but there are two kinds of AutoComplete
>   features in Windows. The first is simply called AutoComplete which is
>   a kind of automatic suggestion feature. In this case you get to see a
>   drop-down list when you start typing. The second is Inline
>   AutoComplete. In this case, the line you are typing is automatically
>   completed, if you have typed the same letters before.
>
> Most of you must be aware of it and in fact must already be using it
>   too – but you not have been aware of the difference.
>
> The AutoComplete feature may be turned on by default, but Inline
>   AutoComplete is not. If you wish, you can enable or disable the
>   autocomplete and the inline autocomplete features in Internet Explorer
>   as well as Windows Explorer too.
>
> **Enable or Disable AutoComplete**
>
> Open Internet Explorer > Internet Options > Content tab. Here click on
>   the AutoComplete Settings button.
>
> [image]
>
> Here you can select or de-select the check-boxes for the items for which you wish to enable or disable autocomplete feature. You have the option to use autocomplete for Address bar, Forms and user names and passwords. You can also if you wish, delete all autocomplete history here.
>
> **Enable or Disable Inline AutoComplete**
>
> You can also, if you wish, enable the Inline AutoComplete feature in
>   Windows Explorer and Run dialog box too. To do so, open Internet
>   Explorer > Internet Options > Advanced tab.
>
> Scroll down to the following items:
>
> - Use inline AutoComplete in the Internet Explorer address bar and Open Dialog
> - Use inline AutoComplete in the Windows Explorer and Run Dialog
>
> [image]
>
> You may see that the first option is already checked. If you wish to enable inline auto-complete in Windows Explorer too, check the 2nd option. Click Apply > OK.

Comment: I did both previously. Even I add string value 'AutoSuggest' and add 'yes' to this value of AutoComplete key of windows registry. But still the browsing list of windows explorer is empty.